# Best way to extend CKEDITOR.styles?

Tags: ckeditor

I feel like I need to change a couple methods in style.js in order to integrate it into my app.  What is a "best practice" for adding methods or even overriding methods in core objects? I plan on doing upgrades in the future, so I don't want to edit the style.js file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to extend CKEditor is to create plugins for it.

If you have to modify something inside a closure then a plugin won't work for you and you'll have to get the source code and modify it and from then on keep using that patch.

Comment: I've created a plugin whose purpose is to override methods in the CKEDITOR.style object. For example, In that plugin, I have
        CKEDITOR.style.checkElementMatch = function(...) {...}
...to override the checkElementMatch function. Are you saying this is a bad idea?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that it's a bad idea. I didn't write anything like that. If using a plugin is good enough for you, go for it.